# Why is this map diagonalisable?

Tags: coxeter-groups

In some lecture notes about Reflection Groups, the writer constructs a vector space based on a Coxeter-system. For every $s \in S$ where $(W|S)$ is a Coxeter-system, he calls the related basis vector $\alpha_s$. He constructs the vector space $V$ as follows:
$$V = \bigoplus_{s \in S} \mathbb{R} \alpha_s$$
and assigns the symmetrical bilinear form $B: V \times V \to \mathbb{R}, \;B(\alpha_s,\alpha_t) \mapsto -\cos \frac{\pi}{m_{st}}$ to it, where $m_{st}$ is the entry in the Coxeter-matrix belonging to $s, t \in S$ and $\frac{\pi}{\infty} := 0$. Furthermore, he defines a map
$$\sigma: S \to \mathrm{GL}(V) = \mathrm{Aut}(V), \;\; s \mapsto \sigma_s: \lambda \mapsto \lambda - 2B(\lambda,\alpha_s) \alpha_s$$
which, if I understood correctly, assigns to every $s \in S$ a mirroring $\sigma_s$ at the "hyperplane" (in the sense of the bilinear form $B(\cdot, \cdot)$) perpendicular to the basis vector $\alpha_s$. By plugging in, we can verify that indeed $\sigma_s(\lambda)=\lambda$ for $\lambda \in \{\lambda \in V | \; B(\lambda,\alpha_s) = 0\}$ and $\sigma_s(\alpha_s) = -\alpha_s$.

Did I understand the motivation behind these definitions/constructions correctly so far?

Now, suddenly, the writer states that $\sigma_s$ is diagonalisable. However, in the following he doesn't seem to actually use this fact.

My question is: How can I easily see that this map is diagonalisable? Most statements similar to this in the lecture notes are explained at least briefly, whereas this is not, which is why I think it has to be "trivial". And also, why is it important that this map is diagonalisble? In the following, only one proposition is being proved, stating that for $(W,S)$ and the corresponding vector space with the previous bilinear form, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\sigma: W \to O(B)$ with $\sigma(s) = \sigma_s$ for all $s \in S$.

Thank you very much in advance for any answers.

Comment: It seems you are pretty close to giving a basis of eigenvectors for $ \sigma_s $ from the claims about what it does on $ \alpha_s $ and on vectors "orthogonal" to $ \alpha_s $ in bilinear form $B$.  Can't we construct a basis of eigenvectors (and thus show $ \sigma_s $ diagonalizable) by extending $\{  \alpha_s \}$ to a basis and subtracting the appropriate multiples of $\alpha_s$ from each added basis element (to make them "orthogonal" to $\alpha_s$ in $B$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a basis of $\{\lambda \in V | \; B(\lambda,\alpha_s) = 0\}$. Together with $\alpha_s$ this gives you a basis of $V$ which diagonalises $\sigma_s$. This is a direct consequence of the properties of $\sigma_s$ you listed.

Comment: It might be worth adding that since the Coxeter matrix diagonal entries are 1's, the bilinear form $B(\alpha_s,\alpha_s) = 1$, and thus any vector in $V$ can be offset by a multiple of $\alpha_s$ to get one in $\{\lambda \in V | B(\lambda,\alpha_s) = 0 \}$.

Comment: @hardmath: that's correct. Thank you for the elaboration.